# Time-series modeling on a panel dataset

Tags: time-series, python, modeling

I have been trying to do some predictive modeling using models such as ARMA on a panel data set in python. The dependent variable in my problem is sales, and I have the sales time series of different SKUs (products). My question is how can I model this data set? should I fit a separate ARMA model on each product's time series? or is there a way to fit an ARMA model on the whole data set having variable coefficients?

Comment: It is apparently easy to forecast such SKU panels when one already has a model, but it's hard as hell to precisely fit the parameters for such a model with historical data. I am almost certain that you'll need to write your own package to do it, and when you do, you won't share it, because it's gonna give your firm a huge commercial advantage.

Answer (score 0):

The answer really depends on what you are trying to forecast:

- If it's sales of all sold products (sum) then you will only use one ARIMA model fitted on daily sales; the more aggregate the data is the easier it is to forecast i.e. the more predictable is its behavior.
- If it is each product's daily sales then you might need to use an ARIMA model for each one of them and you could also use a hierarchical forecasting strategy (`hts` package on python).
- If you believe that these products sales affect each other then you might as well opt for a multivariate forecaster such as `VAR`.